# getting certain portion of nsstring

Tags: ios, nsstring

I have string as follows in objective c

```
   NSString *str = @"access_token=E2JmCPLtVySGn-cGGJGGnQ&email=abc@gmail.com";
```

How can i get only **E2JmCPLtVySGn-cGGJGGnQ** ?

Comment: What have you tried to solve this issue yourself? Post your code so we can help you.

Comment: What happens in Xcode if you enter Command-Shift-0?

Comment: Most simply you can try `stringFromIndex` and `stringToIndex` method if the "access_token=" part is fixed. Many other ways to search for a portion of string including regex based are available. Google it.

Comment: Everybody is a noob once, at least point him in the right direction. You need to look up the `rangeOfString` method of NSString

Comment: Well, you could start by reading the spec for NSString.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a Regular Expression (RegEx) to find character patterns.

The pattern matching syntax can be found in the ICU User Guide [Regular Expressions](http://userguide.icu-project.org/strings/regexp)

In the example the pattern is: find the first "=" and all characters up to but not including the character "&". In the pattern '(?<=access_token=)" is a look-behind assertion meaning that the "access_token=" must precede the matched text, "[^&]+" the brackets the "[]" mean a character class, the "^" al but the following character, the "+" means one or more.

```
NSString *str = @"access_token=E2JmCPLtVySGn-cGGJGGnQ&email=abc@gmail.com";
NSString *regexPattern = @"(?<=access_token=)[^&]+";
NSString *found = nil;

NSRange range = [str rangeOfString:regexPattern options:NSRegularExpressionSearch];
if (range.location != NSNotFound) {
    found = [str substringWithRange:range];
}

NSLog(@"Range: %@", NSStringFromRange(range));
NSLog(@"found: %@", found);
```

NSLog output if found:

> Range: {13, 22}
>   found: E2JmCPLtVySGn-cGGJGGnQ

Comment: Nice explanation, it should work in a scenario where the access_token= will be the first = sign, and the next & will always happen on the next argument because of the nature of URL schemes.

Comment: Updated to use a "Look-behind assertion" for the leading "access_token=" so the range found is exactly the range of the desired text.

Answer (score 1):

There is a method of the NSString class called `rangeOfString:` that returns an `NSRange` struct. If you know that your returned value always has the text `access_token=` and also includes `&email` and the format is always the same, you can use this `rangeOfString:` method to sniff out the token.

```
NSRange accessTokenRange = [str rangeOfString:@"access_token="];
//this would return (0,13) for index:0, length: 13
NSRange emailRange = [str rangeOfString:@"&email="];
//this would return (34,7) 
NSInteger tokenLength = ( emailRange.location + 1 ) - accessTokenRange.length;
//the point where &email begins is at index 34, but it starts at 0
//so it's actually the 35th character
//the access_token= string is 13 characters long, so 35-13 = 22
//so you know that the actual token value is 22 characters long
NSRange trueTokenRange = NSMakeRange(accessTokenRange.length,tokenLength);
NSString *tokenSubstring = [str substringWithRange:trueTokenRange];
```

I don't think my math is off, zero indexing can introduce off by 1 errors if you're not careful, I usually have NSLog going on each range so I can double check where I need to add or subtract 1. But essentially you'll be starting at the 14th character, which is index 13 of the string, and reading the next 22 characters.

Comment: `tokenLength` is one to long, change to: `NSInteger tokenLength =  emailRange.location - accessTokenRange.length;`